# Thunderbird: Exporting/importing mail and contacts

Tags: email, thunderbird, export, import

I have an old laptop that had Thunderbird installed on it. I just bought a new one and have installed the latest version of Thunderbird (v31.3.0) on it. I'm looking to:

- Transfer all the emails of my Inbox/Sent folders on the old Thunderbird instance (running on my old machine) to the Inbox/Sent folders on my new one; and
- Transfer all "contacts" from my old Thunderbird instance to my new one, such that, when I go to compose a new email, and I begin typing in the name of the recipient (in the **To:** field), Thunderbird should auto-complete for me.

Is this possible to do? If so, how? If not, then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had my same thunderbird mail data through several computers, just moving the stuff across from system to system.  This also works in multiple-boot: you can hook thunderbird up to two different operating systems.

```
To connect thunderbird to an extant mail file (in h\email)

exit all instances of thunderbird
cd \user\username\appdata\
 ren thinderbird thunderbird2
mklnk /j thunderbird h\email
restart thunderbird

This creates the file at the appropriate location.

You just need to zip h:\email periodically!

W

Alternately  This is the correct method

1  alter the shortcut to add option -P
2.  start this, the default should show the Profile manager
3.  Create a new profile, hight Wendy
4.  Point it to the email directory
    zb  k:\data\email\[random].name
5.  remove the -P icon
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I have used in the past for similar functions is to use the [MozBackup program](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/).

Basically, you just need to make sure that the old and new computers both have the same version of Thunderbird on them (i.e., 31.3.0) then run MozBackup from the old computer.  This will take you through a brief wizard where you can select the various items to backup.  If you so select, it will take all your contacts, emails, and preferences and bundle them up into a single backup file.  Then you merely transfer that file over to the new computer, rerun MozBackup and point the restore feature to the backup file previously created.